# Extract column of doubles from a DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there an easier way to achieve the following?

```
var obj = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
          select row["DOUBLEVALUE"];

double[] a = Array.ConvertAll<object, double>(obj.ToArray(), o => (double)o);
```

I'm extracting a column from a `DataTable` and storing the column in an array of `double`s.

Assume that `table` is a `DataTable` containing a column called "DOUBLEVALUE" of type `typeof(Double)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = (from row in table.AsEnumerable()
      select row.Field<double>("DOUBLEVALUE")).ToArray();
```

The `.ToArray()` bit is optional, of course; without the `ToArray()`, you'll get an enumerable sequence of doubles instead of an array - it depends whether you need to read it once or twice. If you have nulls in the data, use `<double?>` instead.

(note that this needs a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll, and a "using System.Data;" statement - this brings the `.Field<T>(...)` extension methods into play)

Answer (score 2):

```
double[] a = (from row in table.AsEnumerable()
              select Convert.ToDouble( row["DOUBLEVALUE"] )).ToArray();
```

If you have rows that may have null values for that column, add `where row["DOUBLEVALUE"] != null` before the select.